# How to create sp_executesql to drop tables dynamicaly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sp-executesql

For some reasons, I am trying to create a dynamic script to drop tables that I created before. I couldnt do the syntax right and I need help for this matter.

When I run my script, it gives the error:

> "Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'."

and this is my script. It has an error in `sp_executesql` statement, I guess. How can I fix this?

```
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tmpTableName VARCHAR(max);
SET @tmpTableName = '##gmAAA_COLLATION';

SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE @tmpTableName';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@tmpTableName NVARCHAR(max)', @tmpTableName;
```

Comment: how did you create that global temp table in the first place ? Also dynamcially ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this with static SQL, i.e. a table name can never be a parameter in SQL statements like these. This is also true for column names, schema names etc.

If you want to do this using `sp_executesql`, you can build the SQL dynamically as follows:

```
SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@tmpTableName);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

---

PS: The `@stmt` parameter of the `sp_executesql` procedure needs to be of type `NVARCHAR(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE '+@tmpTableName;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: miss a `+` to concatenate the @tblTableName to the DROP TABLE command

Answer (score 1):

The [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) requires nvarchar for the @stmt and @params parameters

so change the data Types of variables form `varchar` to be `nvarchar` as following

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tmpTableName VARCHAR(max);
```

Comment: I already did that but now it says "Incorrect syntax near '@tmpTableName'."

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:-

```
    SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE @tmpTableName'; EXEC (@sql)

OR

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @tmpTableName NVARCHAR(max)
SET @tmpTableName = '##gmAAA_COLLATION';


SET @sql = 'DROP TABLE'+QUOTENAME(@tmpTableName);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@tmpTableName NVARCHAR(max)',@tmpTableName
```

Comment: I need to use sp_executesql because I might use INSERT statemtn instead of DROP

Comment: @Mansoor what is the purpose of `@tmpTableName` inside the Dynamic Query ? It is not used at all